# bash script to ssh multiple servers in a Loop and issue commands

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a text file in which I have a list of servers. I'm trying to read the server one by one from the file, `SSH` in the server and execute `ls` to see the directory contents. My loop runs just once when I run the `SSH` command, however, for `SCP` it runs for all servers in the text file and exits, I want the loop to run till the end of text file for SSH. Following is my bash script, how can I make it run for all the servers in the text file while doing `SSH`?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    name=$line
    ssh abc_def@$line "hostname; ls;"
#   scp /home/zahaib/nodes/fpl_* abc_def@$line:/home/abc_def/
done < $1
```

I run the script as `$ ./script.sh hostnames.txt`

Comment: take a look at http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/

Comment: @D.Shawley, I'm aware of parallel-ssh. I was wondering if this can be done using simple SSH!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem with this code is that `ssh` starts reading data from stdin, which you intended for `read line`. You can tell `ssh` to read from something else instead, like `/dev/null`, to avoid eating all the other hostnames.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    ssh abc_def@"$line" "hostname; ls;" < /dev/null
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Yeah, this works great! could you elaborate on why SSH starts reading stdin data? Thanks.

Comment: `ssh` reads stdin and sends it to the remote server to let you interact with remote programs. It doesn't know that `hostname; ls;` will just ignore that data.

Answer (score 9):

A little more direct is to use the -n flag, which tells ssh not to read from standard input.

Answer (score 3):

Change your loop to a for loop:

```
for server in $(cat hostnames.txt); do
    # do your stuff here
done
```

It's not parallel ssh but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I open-sourced a command line tool called [Overcast](https://github.com/andrewchilds/overcast) to make this sort of thing easier.

First you import your servers:

```
overcast import server.01 --ip=1.1.1.1 --ssh-key=/path/to/key
overcast import server.02 --ip=1.1.1.2 --ssh-key=/path/to/key
```

Once that's done you can run commands across them using wildcards, like so:

```
overcast run server.* hostname "ls -Al" ./scriptfile
overcast push server.* /home/zahaib/nodes/fpl_* /home/abc_def/
```

Comment: Thanks for making this available, still have to explore it, looks pretty neat!