# why does my shell script exit?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a machine list where a service is running in each of those machines. I'm trying to figure out which services logged a particular string. So i wrote a shell script to log in to the server and grep for the logs:

```
while read line
do
  echo ====
  echo $line
  ssh root@$line "grep 'my test string' /abc/*/logs/stderr"
  echo $line
  echo ==========
done
```

I'm running this by `sh script.sh < /tmp/machine-list`
/tmp/machine-list has one host name per line.

But after logging into a single machine and echoing the second `===` the script exits.

Comment: It's CentOS6. and if i comment out ssh line, it parses all the lines

Comment: Please, would you mind posting here the output and error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this, I suspect shell expansion :

```
while read line
do
  echo ====
  echo $line
  ssh root@$line <<'EOF'
  grep 'my test string' /abc/*/logs/stderr
EOF
  echo $line
  echo ==========
done
```

Comment: I do not think so. I used many times the `ssh` command shown above and I had no problem.

Comment: Everything is worth trying so my opinion the solution looks great try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, but I think file descriptor opened by `while` is closed when the ssh session ends.
Following works.

```
hosts=$(cat /tmp/machine-list)

for line in $hosts; do
    echo ====
    echo $line
    ssh root@$line "grep 'my test string' /abc/*/logs/stderr"
    echo $line
    echo ==========
done
```

---

Update

My guess was close.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107800/using-while-loop-to-ssh-to-multiple-servers
[bash script to ssh multiple servers in a Loop and issue commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254906/bash-script-to-ssh-multiple-servers-in-a-loop-and-issue-commands)

Comment: Better to read into an array in the script `hosts=( $( </tmp/machine-list ) )` and then loop: `for line in "${hosts[@]}"`. I agree that `ssh` is causing `stdin` to close after executing the command on the remote host. I don't have a reference handy and am a bit bewildered myself.

Comment: Check those related questions. Why is it better to use an array?

Comment: Because you are embedding newlines in a single variable and relying on word-splitting being set to default to allow you to get `lines` back out of `hosts`. Reading into an array eliminates `IFS` influence on you ability to get your values back out :)